# removing words from strings without affecting words using python spacy

Tags: python, string, nlp, spacy

I am using spacy, i have a list of sentences i want to remove stop words and punctuation from it.

```
for i in sentences_list: 
for token in docfile:
    if token.is_stop or token.is_punct and token.text in i[1]:
       i[1] = i[1].replace(token.text, '') 
print(sentences_list)
```

but it affect words too for example the word `I` is a stop word so the word `big` becomes `bg`.

Comment: For the record removing stopwords and punctuation is not going to help with modern NLP models, you shouldn't have to do this most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```py
" ".join([token.text for token in doc if not token.is_stop and not token.is_punct])
```

Here is a sample code demo:

```py
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
sentences_list = ["I like big planes.", "No, I saw no big flames."]
new_sentence_list = []
for i in sentences_list:
    doc = nlp(i)
    new_sentence_list.append(" ".join([token.text for token in doc if not token.is_stop and not token.is_punct]))
```

The `new_sentence_list` is now:

```py
['like big planes', 'saw big flames']
```